# How do I implement an interface from a different file?

Tags: java, interface, implementation

I am new to Java and I was wondering how I would go about doing something like this.

Interface file:

```
public interface ExampleInterface {
    void doSomething();
}
```

Implementation file (in same directory):

```
public class ExampleImplementation implements ExampleInterface {
    void doSomething() {
        // code goes here
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Hehe, nobody noticed that I forgot to add the class keyword.

Comment: you'd do it exactly like that. what is your question precisely?

Comment: Well... that's it. The interface declares methods, the implementation implements them. Your example code is valid. What more are you wondering about?

Comment: In other language you have to specify that you are using another file. Are you saying that I can keep them in the same directory and that this would work fine?

Comment: The implementation needs to find the interface. That can be accomplished by having an import statement for the interface, giving the complete name for the interface when you declare you implement it,  or having interface and implementation in the same package. Usually you have a package statement in the beginning of the file. Usually files are located in directories reflecting their package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything looks good in your example.

Remeber that java has packages and in above example you don't precise package so interface and class are in default package. You must put this files in some directory and then compile class file.

To compile use:

```
javac ExampleImplementation.java
```

Or better, use some IDE (Eclipse or Netbeans) then if something will be wrong IDE will be notify you and tell what error you encountered.

Answer (score 2):

Uh, just put them in the same package. To answer your question- yes, just put them in the same directory and they'll work. But even if you don't put them in the same directory, they can still work, except you have to do the correct imports.

Answer (score 1):

That's how you do it.  You just have to compile both into byte code and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

If both files are in the same folder, you should not need to do anything.

Be careful that your filenames should be the same than the name of the class/interface they contain (with the `.java` extension).

Answer (score 1):

Please just read this:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html